# crashing with threads in android program

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Why does this code crash the app and force me to close it?
it keeps crashing for some reason 
I dont understand why but this code should be for understanding threads

```
public class ThreadE extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Do Time Consuming task!");
        setContentView(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);}
        public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(10000);


     }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Activitys `onCreate` is handled by system and it's run on the UI thread, You cannot call `Thread.sleep()` there.

Answer (score 2):

This class is extending Activity which means it will be on the Main (UI)thread.The problem is calling using this code:
 [[ Thread.sleep(10000) ]]
Which will block the main thread for 10 seconds ,We should never block the main thread
Try inheriting from Thread or AsyncTask